# "OSError: cannot identify image file" opening image with PIL/Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to get some code working that has broken but was working before. I have a PNG file on my desktop and I simply want to open it using the Image module from PIL.

```
from PIL import Image
img_dir = r'C:\Users\DylanDB\Desktop\square.png'
img = Image.open(img_dir)
```

This is a remake of my more advanced code that it happens in as well. The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DylanDB/Desktop/img_test.py", line 5, in <module>
    img = Image.open(img_dir)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2317, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file 'C:\\Users\\DylanDB\\Desktop\\square.png'
```

Comment: First thing you should do is try to open the image file in some other application and see if it it works. That will tell you if the file is any good. If not, you're likely out of luck. If it works, then you'll need add a link to the image file, which you'll need to upload somewhere (like [Imgur](http://imgur.com/)) to your question so others can download it.

Comment: I just tried to open it in windows photo viewer and it was unable to. I deleted and remade the file, and it appears to be working fine again. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error and it was due to the file was recently created and not closed properly before opening with the Image.open(). After closing the file f.close() it werked as expect

Answer (score 1):

I found that the file was a corrupted image.